# Append subnetworks to existing Cloud NAT using gcloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I want to add a new subnet as mapping to existing Cloud NAT in google cloud using gcloud cli.

`gcloud compute routers nats update NAME --router=ROUTER --nat-custom-subnet-ip-ranges=SUBNETWORK[:RANGE_NAME],[…]`

Using the above command I am able to update NAT with required subnets , but it wipes the existing subnets that were already mapped and keeps only the new added subnet.
I want to append my subnet to existing list of subnets when custom mapping is selected for NAT.

Is there any way I can achieve this using gcloud ?

Comment: Specify all subnets with the command. The command does not combine the current subnets with the new ones.

Comment: Actually I am automating a flow where I to need to add a newly created subnet. Specifying all subnets will require me to first get all existing subnet mapping from NAT. Also when custom mapping is selected and we describe NAT , it can have subnets with ALL_IP_RANGES, when updating gcloud there is no such option and have to rely on `--nat-custom-subnet-ip-ranges=SUBNETWORK[:RANGE_NAME],[…]`

Answer (score 0):

This command is mainly used for **‘To change subnets and IP address resources associated with NAT’** not for appending the subnets in existing configuration. I tried the mentioned command in my environment and it seems that the command is replacing the existing subnets with new ones. Refer to [1].

To append a newly created subnet in current configuration, you have to explicitly mention both existing and new subnets in the command line, refer to [2]. Otherwise, you have to customize your command line in such a way where you can pull out all the existing subnets and then add to the list of newly created subnets for update.

As an alternative solution to CLI, I would suggest you go with a Cloud Console.

Under NAT mapping, select option **‘Primary and secondary ranges for all subnets’** so that newly created  subnets will also get added into existing subnets that were already mapped.
Refer to the provided screenshot.

```
[1]
gcloud compute routers nats update NAT-CONFIG
     --router=ROUTER    
     --auto-allocate-nat-external-ips
     --nat-custom-subnet-ip-ranges=SUBNET2
```

Output: Replacing the existing SUBNET1 with new SUBNET2.

```
[2]
gcloud compute routers nats update NAT-CONFIG
     --router=ROUTER    
     --auto-allocate-nat-external-ips
     --nat-custom-subnet-ip-ranges=SUBNET1,SUBNET2
```

Output: Keeping both SUBNET1 and SUBNET2 in configuration.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/routers/nats/update

[image: Screenshot]